# Delete database in Blackberry Torch - Phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, lawnchair

I am building cross platform applications using Phonegap. Additionally I use [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) to store data in the local database.

My question is quite general. I install an application that I built for iPhone, Android and Blackberry, then create some items to store in the database. This is done without any problem on any platform, however I would like to delete the whole database so I delete the application and reinstall it. On iPhone and Android the database is cleared automatically, however on Blackberry the items are still stored in the database.

I know that I could use localStorage.clear() in my javascript code, however I need to achieve clearing the database without modifying my application.

So why is the database not deleted when I uninstall a Blackberry applocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database on BlackBerry is not part of application sandbox as it's done on Android and iPhone. As well there is no documented or well defined way to know if your app is going to be uninstalled.

You could encrypt database on BB.